# Cleaning up activities in android

Tags: android

I have four activities a,b,c,d. Activity a is the main activity which then calls b,c and d which then does some computation. I know I can prevent the activity from building up in my application by `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in those activites . But the issue is if I am in activity c,when I press the back button I want to go to b, but if d finishes I want b and c to be removed and only a to displayed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you already coded for the back button in each activity?

Comment: Nope. I havent overridden the back button as I think its best to leave the function of the back button to the android system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in each of your activities, changing it slightly each time. That way you override the back button's normal function

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            //start the desired activity
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Also, if you are only supporting android 2.0+ then you can use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // start your desired activity here
    return;
}
```

Just put either of these in each of your activities, then start the correct activity

To close one specific activity, look at this page - [How to clear specific activity from the stack history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history)

Comment: The issue is not that I want to override the back button but to close n activities which have already piled up onto my stack.

Comment: Can you do this with `finish()` after you have started your new activity?

Comment: Nope. This will simply close all activites - If I am in activity c and I use finish() it will close b when I want to close activity b,c only if activity d has finished. I guess my best bet at this time is to use startActivityForResult() in my activities

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history

Comment: Following the other question/answer he has linked, see mdelolmo's answer, not the accepted answer. It shows how to clear the stack. :)

Comment: Yep. That kind of addresses what I want but the problem is there is no condition I can compare with to add the flag. I dont always want the activity stack to be cleared. Only if activity d has been executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you just put that particular price of code in activity d only?

Comment: Okay. I did it using startActivityForResult(). I guess that is the most efficient way of doing it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be acheived by making sure that you use a finish() function after every startActivity function. Except in the activity which you want to be displayed in the end.

So... Here is how it looks like

Code in A:

```
startActivity(Intent to start activity B);
```

Code in B:

```
startActivity(Intent to start activity C); 
Finish();
```

Code in C:

```
startActivity(Intent to start activity D); 
Finish();
```

This will ensure that whenever Activity D is completed, activity C will also be completed because of Finish. As this C is also completed, Finish() in activity B will close B. As there is no Finish() in Activity A, that activity will be displayed on the screen.

If you want to come to Activity A only after D is completed, you will have to use startActivityForResult and process the result and use IF to conditionally execute Finish statement in B & C.