# Request permission dialog pauses my activity

Tags: android

I am asking for permission inside `onActivityResult` of my activity and what is happening is that  my activity is being paused while request permission dialog is displayed. Why is that and can I somehow prevent it?

All I doing is asking for permission in a normal way:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS_CODE);
```

Comment: "Why is that" -- you are starting another activity (the request permission dialog). "can I somehow prevent it?" -- do not use `dangerous` permissions, so you do not need to call `requestPermissions()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is happening is that my activity is being paused while request
>   permission dialog is displayed. Why is that?

[requestPermissions docs says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

> `This method may start an activity allowing the user to choose which`
>   `permissions to grant and which to reject. Hence, you should be`
>   `prepared that your activity may be paused and resumed`. Further,
>   granting some permissions may require a restart of you application. In
>   such a case, the system will recreate the activity stack before
>   delivering the result to your onRequestPermissionsResult(int,
>   String[], int[]).

Although an another solution is move your code in `onStop` if possible and suitable

Answer (score 2):

**Source code of method Activity#requestPermissions:**

```
public final void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("requestCode should be >= 0");
    }
    if (mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time");
        // Dispatch the callback with empty arrays which means a cancellation.
        onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, new String[0], new int[0]);
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().buildRequestPermissionsIntent(permissions);
    startActivityForResult(REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_WHO_PREFIX, intent, requestCode, null);
    mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest = true;
}
```

We can clearly see that a new activity is opened. Hence `onPause` in the calling activity will be surely called. So this is the **expected behavior.**

**If you want to prevent pausing your activity, make sure you already have the required permissions before opening that activity.**

If your activity is main activity, add an splash activity. Otherwise check for permissions before opening your activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is also possibility that, your Activity (say, MainActivity) that invoking the

```
requestPermissions()
```

might have been declared flag

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in the Manifest.

Therefore the MainActivity is paused, and eventually `finish()`'d during `requestPermissions()`.
From Android documentation [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

> You cannot request a permission if your activity sets noHistory to
>   true in the manifest

If that is the case.. 
you may do a `finish()` [clear specific activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history)  programmatically inside the `MainActivity { .. }` to remove it from the activities stack, not in the Manifest.

This was in my case !