# Launch Mode Singletop not working with permisison dialog showing

Tags: android, android-permissions, launchmode

I have an `Activity` with launch mode `singleTop` which shows permission dialog.

But when permission dialog is present and a new Intent comes for that activity , another instance is created .
`onNewIntent()` doesn't get called.

Any workaround for this?

Below is the manifest entry.

```
<activity
        android:name=".auth.activity.AJRAuthActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

The way I start this activity:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(context, AJRAuthActivity.class);
context.startActivity(loginIntent);
```

Comment: Add some code to explain problem . and manifest entry.

Comment: Can you add the launchMode to your calling intent as well: `loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

Comment: well it works if permission popup is not there

Comment: are you requesting permission in `onCreate()` ?

Comment: @Sagar yes requesting in onCreate

Comment: try to request it in `onStart` and check if it behaves correctly. It worked for me previously

Comment: ok will try and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the permission dialog usually starts another `Activity` (a system `Activity`) on top of your `Activity`. In this case, your `Activity` will be paused (`onPause()` is called). At that point, your `Activity` is no longer the top `Activity` on the stack, so that another launch of the `Activity` will create another instance, even if "singleTop" launch mode and/or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is specified.

See [Request permission dialog pauses my activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827032/request-permission-dialog-pauses-my-activity)

To get around this, you should ensure that you have all the permissions that you might need as early as possible, or rearchitect your application so that you don't have the problem of multiple instances.