# Return back to Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

- **I have** `MainActivity` with `BottomNav` which includes 3 Fragments A, B, and C.
- From Fragment A, I can go to Activity A and from, Activity A I can go to Activity B.
- Now **I want to** return to specifically Fragment A from Activity B by pressing a Back button while skipping Activity A.
- **I've tried** `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` in Activity A before starting Activity B and also explicitly starting an Intent to `MainActivity` from Activity B but it's not giving the result I want and of course it doesn't seem like an efficient way to do it. How do I return back to the fragment?

Comment: Did you try overriding back press?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi I did try using onBackPressed but it will exit the app. If I were to write my own onBackPress, what should I write in order to return to FragmentA specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**

You need to finish Activity A after launching intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**case 2**

If you want to come back on Activity A at some point then what you need is passing some flag from Activity B to A. And run this code at the beginning of your activity A.

```
if(extras.getBoolean("NameOfFlag", false))
    {
       ActivityA.finish();
    }
```

send flag by using this code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("NameOfFlag", true);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Remember to `finish()` Activity when you don't need to come back. In this case ActivityB .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the ideal solution but should work

In Activity B

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {   
   Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, MainActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("cameFromActivityB", true);
   startActivity(i);
 }
```

In Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent.getExtras();
    if(extras.getBoolean("cameFromActivityB", false))
    {
       loadFragmentA();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look for the ideal solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history

Answer (score 0):

// Inside the onCreate on every Activity://

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("name of the Activity here"); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnable(true);
```

//then go to the manifest file in //

//before that closing bracket
set the order of your Activities; example
(you have three activities,the Main Activity,Activity2,Activity3)//

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" 
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when you start your ActivityB from ActivityA just finish your activityA by finish() method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

By doing this you will not be redirected to ActivityA instead, you will be directy redirected to your main activity when you press back button from your activityB.